# Success ratio improvement

Tags: statistics

I got the following question from a friend:

**Suppose the success ratio improved from 98% to 99.5%. What is the ratio of the improvement?**

This is the answer I gave him which he deemed correct:

**99.5% success ratio means 5 failures out of 1000 attempts ... 98% success ratio means 2 failures out of 100 attempts which is 20 failures out of 1000 attempts ... we got from 20 failures to 5 failures which is a 4 times improvement**

What if I, however, took the complementary approach, like this?

**99.5% success ratio means 995 successes out of 1000 attempts ... 98% success ratio means 98 successes out of 100 attempts which is 980 successes out of 1000 attempts ... we got from 980 successes to 995 which is a cca 1.015 times improvement**

It seems very strange to me that these two results don't match. What is it that I'm not getting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers do not match because in the first instance you are getting the ratio between no. of failures and in the second instance you are comparing the no. of successful attempts.